# Google Drive Bandwidth limitation for billed plans? or any way to request more bandwidth if have any limitation

Tags: google-drive-api, bandwidth

I Have a web application that share about 30 GB of  education material with its users, I have about 10000 users, that commonly about 200 user downloads the education materials (about 500 MB for every file) concurrently, I need to give my users a high speed download experience.

So I decided to upload my files to a billed Google drive plan, and using *Google Drive SDK* to make them able to download that files from Google drive. Before I start to programming *Google Drive SDK*, I need to know if Google drive have any bandwidth limitation for downloads in its billed plans?

For exemple 5000GB per month etc...
And if have, is it possible to request more bandwidth from Google Drive?

Are you have a better suggestion to do this job instead of using Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, Google Drive does not have bandwidth limitations (see *[Will Google Drive take all of my internet bandwidth?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490100?hl=en)*) However, Google Drive does have quota limitations, like any other Google API. It should be unlikely that you hit those limits, but you can check the quota limitations in your developer console.